# Same data repeat show in the playground when sequelize include sum use

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

When I am trying to run my sequelize code. In include, I do a sum. The sum is from 3 values. But my problem is the output shows 3 times the same values.

```
await models.Invoices.findAll({
        where: {partnerId: 1},
        raw: true,
        include: [
            {
                model: models.Corrections,
                attributes: ["invoiceId",[Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('amount')), 'amount']],
                duplicating: true,
                group: ['Corrections.amount'],
                raw: true
            }
        ],
        group: ["invoices.id", "corrections.invoiceId", '"corrections.amount"'],
        order: [[Sequelize.col('"corrections.amount"'), 'ASC']]
    }).then(
        result => {
            console.log("result", result);

            return result;
        }
    )
```

**>> The id 3 show 3 times.**

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "correctionTotal": 200
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "correctionTotal": 3500
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "correctionTotal": 3500
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "correctionTotal": 3500
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "correctionTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "correctionTotal": 0
      },
```

**The result Id: 3 show 3 times. Why this thing shows 3 times. How do I show the id one time?**

Comment: Could you post the sql executed and logged by sequelize?

Comment: Yes. I did that @waynelpu